# How to close a form onclick in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007, I have a button that opens up a form in dialog mode (modal and popup set to true). I'm trying to save the data from that form and then close that form like so:

```
Private Sub Close_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Form, acSaveYes
End Sub
```

The purpose is to add a new record to a table. It accomplishes this, new data is added to the database based on the inputs. However, the form still stay visible. I have also tried this not using dialog mode, and the result has been the same.

Comment: Well, that kinda should work. Is there something on the `Form_Close` event preventing you from closing the form?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth nope nothing in `Form_Close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `DoCmd.Close` the form name, not the actual form object.

```
Private Sub Close_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveYes
End Sub
```

Also, while you're making changes, add `Option Explicit` add the top of your module. This would've made it way easier to spot the bug.  Read [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?461140-Classic-VB-What-is-Option-Explicit-and-why-should-I-use-it) why having `Option Explicit` on is a good idea.